# Changing end-of-list animation in MIUI

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, miui, themes

I really like the Samsung / iOS bounce at the end of lists, and I really dislike the overglow animation from Google. And since I'm only using MIUI ROMs, I'm used to being able to set up everything the way I want it, I decided to ask them the question:

[image: facebook conversation]

And as you can see I received a positive answer. But either it's not true, or I'm completely blind.

The menu option isn't there for me. (I double-checked.) So does anyone know if it's still possible, or why she said this?

Comment: Download the MIUI control panel.

Comment: So it IS possible. I'm not sure if that's what she meant though. If you'd post this as an answer, I'll mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Uri seems not to place it in an answer, I will do so -- to help other searchers see there is an answer ;)

As pointed out, there is a *MIUI control panel*, which should ship with most MIUI ROMs. If it is not included with yours, you will find it in an app called [Extended Settings](https://sites.google.com/site/miuisettings/project-definition).